# Rails jquery render bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to render a bottstrap modal view from a partial using a jquery.

I have a controller `letters_controller.rb` with such code:

```
def new
  @letter = Letter.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

In `views/letters.slim` I have two files: `_new.slim`:

```
       .modal-header
         button.close type="button" data-dismiss="modal"
           i.fa.fa-times
       .modal-title
         h4 style='display: inline; margin-right: 15px' Write a letter
       .modal-body
         p lalallala

       .modal-footer
         button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" Сlose
           .modal-dialog style='width: 700px'
             .modal-content
```

and `new.js.erb`

```
$("#email-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'letters/new') %>");
```

In a calling view I has a button `= link_to new_letter_path, {:id => 'contact-us', :remote => true }`

Also in a calling view I has a `div` where modal should be rendered:
`.modal.fade#email-modal role="dialog" tabindex="-1"`

The problem is that by clicking a button, anything's grayed out like it sould be, but no window appears. I checked a code and found out that jquery do not inserts `_new.slim`'s code into prepared `div`. What it could be about? Thanx!

==================
Logs for pressing a button (I left only those that are connected with that stuff):

```
I, [2016-10-18T22:31:11.380703 #1]  INFO -- : Started GET "/letters/new" for 172.18.0.4 at 2016-10-18 22:31:11 +0000
I, [2016-10-18T22:31:11.404587 #1]  INFO -- : Processing by LettersController#new as JS
D, [2016-10-18T22:31:11.411518 #1] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"...
....
I, [2016-10-18T22:31:11.454585 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered letters/_new.slim (0.1ms)
I, [2016-10-18T22:31:11.459100 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered letters/new.coffee within layouts/application (6.7ms)
I, [2016-10-18T22:31:11.546124 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered application/_support_email.slim (0.1ms)
```

Comment: Can you please add your server logs for this call?

Comment: can you try with specific `render partial: "letters/new"` maybe its just a kind of name conflict.

Comment: @prakashS Logs are in update.

Comment: @sajan If I strictly add `= render partial: ...` into the `#email-modal` `div`, it perfectly renders.
But, I think, it ought to be clear, that I want to send a variable to that partial, so it should be rendered after the call to controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was not in modal, but in `format.js` and executing jquery in `js.erb` file.
I asked [one more question](http://tackoverflow.com/questions/40142099/rails-code-for-format-js-do-not-work/) and the solution was to add `{ render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript' }` after `format.js`

Answer (score 0):

Your _new.slim should be

```
#edit-modal.modal.fade aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" 
   .modal-header
     button.close type="button" data-dismiss="modal"
       i.fa.fa-times
   .modal-title
     h4 style='display: inline; margin-right: 15px' Write a letter
   .modal-body
     p lalallala

   .modal-footer
     button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" Сlose
       .modal-dialog style='width: 700px'
         .modal-content
```

and you need to have div in letters.slim for placing modal content

```
<div id="modalDiv"> </div>
```

Then your new.js should render the partial and trigger the modal to show

```
$("#modalDiv").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'letters/new') %>");
$("#edit-modal").modal("show");
```

Comment: I already had an analogue of `modalDiv`. It's called `#email-modal`. And the problem is the content of `letters/new` do not being added to it.

Comment: I've just decided to test a little bit. So, as far as it written in my code above, a button has an id `contact-us`. I added a line `$("#contact-us").html("lalala");` to my `new.js` file and it also does not work. Content of button leaves unchanged. Is it about JS processed wrong?

Comment: i think you have added the line at the end if previous lines causes error it wont proceed next

Comment: you are trying to show the modal while click then you are trying to replace content to that using modal's id that causes the error.

Comment: I had just solved it. And it was not about a modal or smth like this.
I placed an answer